Typescript dynamic type literals
I recently stumbled upon interesting problem. I'm trying to create a vuejs wizard component which accepts configuration objects. Demo type looks like this:
type WizardConfiguration = {
  steps: Array<{
      name: string,
      fields: {
        fieldName: string;
      }[]
    watchers: (FIELD NAMES ARR) => void
  }>,
  globalWatchers: (ENTIRE STATE FIELD NAMES ARR) => void
}

The problems stands in the watchers line. I want watchers callback to accept array of field names which were specified in the fields array. Example would look like this:
const config: WizardConfiguration = {
  steps: [
   {
      name: "Step 1",
      fields: [
         { fieldName: "Field 1 1" },
         { fieldName: "Field 1 2" }
      ],
      watchers: ([HERE I GET A INTELLISENSE of "Field 1 1", "Field 1 2"]) => {
      // do smth
      }
   },
   {
      name: "Step 2",
      fields: [
         { fieldName: "Field 2 1" },
         { fieldName: "Field 2 2" }
      ],
      watchers: ([HERE I GET A INTELLISENSE of "Field 2 1", "Field 2 2"]) => {
      // do smth
      }
   },
  ],
  globalWatchers: ([HERE I GET INTELLISENSE OF ENTIRE WIZARD STATE - "Field 1 1", "Field 1 2", "Field 2 1", "Field 2 2"])
};

Is something like this event possible in the current state of ts?
Thanks
EDIT 1:
Wizard will preserve the state as reative object. I'd want to go with the flattest object structure as possible, namely. each fieldName in the wizard will be represented by [fieldName]: value in the state object.

There is no specific type that works this way. You can write a generic type along with a helper function to infer the type argument, as shown in this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

It looks excellent. Can you explain what is going on there? Iteration over keyof T where T is array looks tricky. Can't it be simplified?
Also, is NoInfer there really needed?

Are you saying you want me to write an answer? Or do you need me to answer your questions first? If so: it's just a mapped type and is fairly straightforward; as fast as I know that's the simplest way to express the constraint you want. NoInfer might not be "needed" but it conveys that you want to infer T from fields and not from watchers. Is there some constraint about whether something is "needed" vs just "recommended"? Let me know how to proceed.

Also, steps need to be an array of objects, not single objects(wizard can have multiple steps). Each step object should have a watcher callback which accepts its fields as arguments - each step should have its own context. Could you please show me how can it be done?

Hmm, but your example config had a single one, not an array. Your demo type had that [] in there but your demo type is pseudocode so it's very hard to know how to proceed. Could you make sure your question has a [mre] in it so that there's a well-defined use case to test against? If you care about an array, you should make the example an array, preferably one with at least two elements so that we can see nontrivial behavior. Also, could you please respond directly to my questions in the previous comments, so we're on the same page here?

Sure. Sorry for the confusion.

Sure. Sorry for the confusion.
Yes, I'd love to see an final working prototype of your answer even though you helped me alot already :) I updated my pseudocode - it should be fairly understandable now.
Your initial answer works as expected for single "step" object, so what's left is multiplying it somehow. Final result does not have to be strictly identical to my example, if you see better, simpler way to express what I'm trying to achieve please adapt the correct change so answering you question, I'd stick to "recommended" word.

The overall idea is to have declarative way of defining the wizard.
Wizard has steps, step has fields, step has watchers. In addition if possible. I'd love to have "global" watcher callback which provides all the state as args

This is significantly more complex than your original question. It's unfortunate when the scope expands in response to clarifications, as it's not sustainable and adds more work to something instead of focusing it.  Still, this approach is the closest I can get with your given structure. (more...)

(...continued) There might be a better structure but asking for a complete refactoring is probably out of scope for SO (I'd think you want a builder, not an object literal, but this question doesn't ask for a builder). You can't get the nested inference you want directly so you need an intermediate helper function like step(). Does this now fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer (but please, no more additions). If not, what am I still missing?

Helper function does not cause any issue. You are not missing anything, that works cool!

I’ll write an answer when I get a chance.

I'm delighted by your typescript skills. Is there any source you can suggest I can use to improve my skills? :)

I never know what advice to give people when they ask me that. I personally have spent years looking at the language, reading the full typescriptlang.org docs, new release notes, and I try to keep up to date on the github issues, and read the descriptions of the pull requests that are merged. But that's a source in the same way a firehose is a source of drinking water.

There is no specific type in TypeScript corresponding to your requirements. Instead, the closest you can get is to make a generic type like WizardConfiguration<T extends any[][]> where T is meant to be a tuple of tuples of strings.  The idea is that WizardConfiguration<[["a","b"],["c","d"]]> would end up describing a configuration with two steps, the first step having fields "a" and "b" in that order, and the second step having fields "c" and "d" in that order.
The type could look like:
interface WizardConfiguration<T extends string[][]> {
   steps: { [I in keyof T]: Step<T[I]> },
   globalWatchers: (args: TupleFlat<T>) => void;
}

where we have yet to define Step and TupleFlat.
The globalWatches property is a function whose parameter type is TupleFlat<T>, so evidently it should flatten the tuple of tuples into a single one. We want TupleFlat<[["a","b"],["c","d"]]> to be ["a","b","c","d"]. Here's one way to write TupleFlat:
type TupleFlat<T extends any[][], A extends T[number][number][] = []> =
   T extends [infer F extends any[], ...infer R extends any[][]] ?
   TupleFlat<R, [...A, ...F]> : A;

That's a tail-recursive conditional type using variadic tuple types to join tuples.
The steps property of WizardConfiguration<T> is a mapped array type over the tuple-of-strings elements of T, where we take each element T[I] and map it to Step<T[I]>.., that is, steps for WizardConfiguration<[["a","b"],["c","d"]]> becomes [Step<["a","b"]>,Step<["c","d"]>]. So let's define Step:
interface Step<T extends string[]> {
   name: string;
   fields: { [I in keyof T]: { fieldName: T[I] } }
   watchers: (args: T) => void;
}

That defines a single step. Here we have another mapped array type for field, so that for each string element of T we have an object with a fieldName of that property. And then watchers is a method with a parameter of type T.

Now, that means if you want to use the type you need to specify that tuple-of-tuples-of-strings:
const config: WizardConfiguration<[
  ["Field 1 1", "Field 1 2"],
  ["Field 2 1", "Field 2 2"]
]> = {
  steps: [
    {
      name: "Step 1",
      fields: [ { fieldName: "Field 1 1" }, { fieldName: "Field 1 2" }],
      watchers: ([a, b]) => {
        a // (parameter) a: "Field 1 1"
        b // (parameter) b: "Field 1 2"          
      }
    },
    {
      name: "Step 2",
      fields: [ { fieldName: "Field 2 1" }, { fieldName: "Field 2 2" }],
      watchers: ([c, d]) => {
        c // (parameter) c: "Field 2 1"
        d // (parameter) d: "Field 1 2"          
      }
    },
  ],
  globalWatchers: ([e, f, g, h]) => {
    e // (parameter) e: "Field 1 1"
    f // (parameter) f: "Field 1 2"          
    g // (parameter) g: "Field 2 1"
    h // (parameter) h: "Field 2 2"          
  }
}

That works exactly as advertised, but it's redundant because it requires you to write, e.g., "Field 1 1" both in the object literal and in the type.
You can avoid that by writing some generic helper functions to infer the type arguments for you. It would be great if I could write a single wizardConfiguration() function which would take the above object literal and infer the type properly, but this requires inference from nested mapped types and it doesn't seem to function as desired. There are possibly other appropaches, but one easy way to do it is to introduce another helper function step() for each of the steps. Like this:
const wizardConfiguration = <const T extends string[][]>(w: WizardConfiguration<T>) => w;
   
const step = <const T extends string[]>(s: Step<T>) => s;

These functions don't really serve any purpose except to help with type inference.  You write const c = wizardConfiguration({⋯}) instead of const c: WizardCondifiguration<[["a","b"],["c","d"]]> = {⋯}.
Let's test it:
const config = wizardConfiguration({
  steps: [
    step({
      name: "Step 1",
      fields: [{ fieldName: "Field 1 1" }, { fieldName: "Field 1 2" }],
      watchers: ([a, b]) => {
        a // (parameter) a: "Field 1 1"
        b // (parameter) b: "Field 1 2"          
      }
    }),
    step({
      name: "Step 2",
      fields: [{ fieldName: "Field 2 1" }, { fieldName: "Field 2 2" }],
      watchers: ([c, d]) => {
        c // (parameter) c: "Field 2 1"
        d // (parameter) d: "Field 1 2"          
      }
    }),
  ],
  globalWatchers: ([e, f, g, h]) => {
    e // (parameter) e: "Field 1 1"
    f // (parameter) f: "Field 1 2"          
    g // (parameter) g: "Field 2 1"
    h // (parameter) h: "Field 2 2"          
  }
})
// const config: WizardConfiguration<[
//   ["Field 1 1", "Field 1 2"], 
//   ["Field 2 1", "Field 2 2"]
// ]>

That works. The string literal types "Field 1 1", etc., are all just inferred from the initializer. Yes, you have those intermediate step() calls in there, but hopefully it's not too cumbersome to use.

That's the answer to the question as asked. Once you use helper functions you might consider switching to a builder pattern instead, which might look like
const config = WizardConfigBuilder
  .addStep("Step 1", [{ fieldName: "Field 1 1" }, { fieldName: "Field 1 2" }], ([a, b]) => { })
  .addStep("Setp 2", [{ fieldName: "Field 2 1" }, { fieldName: "Field 2 2" }], ([c, d]) => { })
  .addGlobalWatchers(([e, f, g, h]) => { });

where one possible implementation of WizardConfigBuilder might be
class WizardConfigBuilder<T extends string[][] = []> {
  constructor(public steps: { [I in keyof T]: Step<T[I]> }) { }
  addStep<U extends string[]>(
    name: string,
    fields: { [I in keyof U]: { fieldName: U[I] } },
    watchers: (args: U) => void
  ): WizardConfigBuilder<[...T, U]> {
    return new (WizardConfigBuilder as any)([...this.steps, { name, fields, watchers }]);
  }
  addGlobalWatchers(globalWatchers: (args: TupleFlat<T>) => void): WizardConfiguration<T> {
    return { steps: this.steps, globalWatchers };
  }
  static addStep: WizardConfigBuilder<[]>["addStep"] = (...args) => new WizardConfigBuilder([]).addStep(...args)
}

but this answer is already very long and this is somewhat out of scope. I'll leave off the detailed explanation; it's just here as proof of concept that you might find a builder a more friendly experience.
Playground link to code
